# Improve Query for results by Gender

Tags: sql

I have the query below fetching all age ranges in my table for all my farmers but i need the data by gender type.

```
WITH AgeData as
(
  SELECT [sex],
         [dob],
         DATEDIFF(YEAR, [dob], GETDATE()) AS [AGE]
  FROM dbo.Farmers
),
GroupAge AS
(
  SELECT [sex],
         [dob],      
         CASE
             WHEN AGE < 24 THEN 'Under 24'
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 25 AND 30 THEN '25 - 30'
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31 - 40'
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41 - 50'
             WHEN AGE > 50 THEN 'Over 50'
             ELSE 'Invalid Birthdate'
         END AS [Age Groups]
  FROM AgeData
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [AgeGrpCount],[Age Groups]
FROM GroupAge
GROUP BY [Age Groups];
```

If I add this to the code i would get it my gender type for males:

```
WITH AgeData as
(
  SELECT [sex],
         [dob],
         DATEDIFF(YEAR, [dob], GETDATE()) AS [AGE]
  FROM dbo.Farmers
),
GroupAge AS
(
  SELECT [sex],
         [dob],      
         CASE
             WHEN AGE < 24 THEN 'Under 24'
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 25 AND 30 THEN '25 - 30'
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31 - 40'
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41 - 50'
             WHEN AGE > 50 THEN 'Over 50'
             ELSE 'Invalid Birthdate'
         END AS [Age Groups]
  FROM AgeData
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [MaleAgeGrpCount],[Age Groups]
FROM GroupAge
Where sex = 1
GROUP BY [Age Groups];
```

But I would like both a [MaleAgeGrpCount] and a [FemaleAgeGrpCount] Colum Instead where sex = 1 is male and sex = 2 is female.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    [Age Groups],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sex = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [MaleAgeGrpCount],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sex = 2 THEN 1 END) AS [FemaleAgeGrpCount]
FROM GroupAge
GROUP BY [Age Groups];
```

This idea here is to use separate `CASE` expressions to count the male and female records as you aggregate by the age groups.

Comment: Hi, I believed the ELSE 'Invalid Birthdate' clause would have detected future birthdays. However I have records with future birthdays that are not showing up as invalid birthdates. Any reason why or a change i could do to detect this.

Comment: You should open a new question, I think.  If you change the question now, you will invalidate all the answers already given here.